# How to resolve connection error between AWS RDS Oracle & Oracle SQL Developer in macOs

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds

I have created an oracle db using AWS RDS but I couldn't connect with SQL Developer and it always fails with

> IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Vendor code 17002

[image]

I have followed copied the

- **hostname**
- **port** from AWS correctly.

I have double checked my password is also right.

[image]

Any ideas what needs to fixed.

**Update:**

Please find my bill copy here. I applied for free tier and I got such a mamoth bill for just 7 days of trial and test

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's something odd about SID. It's usually the db name. Are you sure that you are using right DB name ?

Comment: I named my db thetest1db..it's part of the hostname also.

Comment: You haven't stated if you validated connectivity to the server.  Since you put a hostname up there, I looked it up and it doesn't resolve.  So maybe that.  The error message is generic and generally means a connectivity error.  You could put garbage in the hostname and make that same error appear.  You need to make sure that hostname is correct to start and that it is reachable over the internet and something is responding at port 1521 at that hostname.

Comment: Can you check whether **Publicly accessible** is marked as **YES** ? You will find this under **Connectivity & Security** tab of the database also like @DubStep mentioned check if you are copying **endpoint** and **port** from the same tab to oracle's Hostname and port.

Comment: It's marked as Publicy accessible to yes indeed .. yes hostname and port is right.I'm confused what else is causing the issue

Comment: @DubStep - How can I check if something is reponding at 1521 and the hostname ? I can check ping from terminal for hostname but not sure about the port

Comment: @King - Can you re-check the **DB name** it's usually found under **Configuration** tab in AWS DB page ? and use the **DB name** found there for **SID** or **Service name** in Oracle SQL Developer. IMO it's usually written as **DATABASE** or **ORCL**.

Comment: Go through this [AWS RDS Article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToOracleInstance.SQLDeveloper.html?fbclid=IwAR0yjUV8Mit9N8gU7sWA_mfPDchtUI3W6qsEGmrZ41N8zNTGGjhkJ-iQBvs) and verify the configuration

Comment: Thanks, I have configured as per the document but problem is remaining

Comment: Can you check if the port number is not locked your machine ?

Comment: Run the following command `nc -vz hostname port` on your terminal. You should get success if there's no problem with **endpoint** and **port** access.

Comment: @King to check port you can use a multitude of tools.  Some examples, telnet to open a connection to the hostname and port Ex: telnet <hostname> <port>
In that command you'd replace <hostname> and <port> with the actual hostname and port values.  Port ping utilities, such as PsPing and portping can also be used.

Comment: I'm getting can not resolve and unknown host .. I tried along with port number also

Comment: Go AWS RDS page , choose your database and scroll down to security group. Delete the inbound rule and add the inbound rule again with default values. This should the problem you are facing.

Comment: @DubStep DuraiamuthanH - I received a bill saying 637.75$ that's quite shocking..it's been just the last week of July and I've got such a lofty bill. I chose free tier I thought it's gonna be free.. never expected any charge at all... Can you please help me out of this ?

Comment: RDS oracle is a paid service indeed , they charge based on the usage apart from their service charge.  If you want to move away , I'd suggest you to Delete all the created DBs first then DB snapshot etc.. and check the bill see what you are being charged for and delete or unsubscribe those services the make a call to the AWS customer care and explain see if you can resolve the payment issue.

Comment: If you don't pay up the bill then they'd terminate your account in three months and charge your account with the money for the upcoming three months as well and if you were ever to open an AWS account they'd prompt for you the pending payment.

Comment: I have updated my question .. i have removed the DB and snapshots and terminated the services as far as I can see.I'm yet to contact aws team.. the amount is so high

Answer (score 0):

Go to **AWS RDS** and click on the **database** and scroll down to **security group** then click on the **inbound rule**

[image]

Take notice of **Inbound rules** and click on **Edit inbound rules**

[image]

Click on **Delete** and Click on **Add rule** and leave the fields untouched.

[image]

FYI:

- Please [follow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToOracleInstance.SQLDeveloper.html?fbclid=IwAR0yjUV8Mit9N8gU7sWA_mfPDchtUI3W6qsEGmrZ41N8zNTGGjhkJ-iQBvs) the link to understand more about setting up the connection with right values.
- Run the following `command nc -vz hostname port` on your **terminal**. You should get success if there's no problem with **endpoint** and **port access**.
- During the connection set up from **oracle sql developer client** , you have to give **database name** in **SID** not **database instance name** this is a common mistake.
- Also it's worth remembering you have to use **endpoint** name from **AWS RDS DB** page for **Host Name** in developer client

**Update:**

With RDS and the Free Tier, we can use the following:

- 750 Hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ db.t2.micro, db.t3.micro, and db.t4g.micro Instances usage running MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL databases each month (applicable DB engines).
- 20 GB of General Purpose (SSD) database storage
- 20 GB of storage for database backups and DB Snapshots

*Preventive measures:*

Enable one of the followings in AWS so that you can keep on eye charges as it happens and prevent this kind of accidents.

1. AWS CloudWatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html
2. AWS Cost Anomaly: https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-anomaly-detection/

***To access Anomaly Detection, make sure that you've enabled Cost Explorer for account***

3. AWS Budgets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/budgets-managing-costs.html

P.S:

Please connect with AWS customer care at the earliest and try explaining this accident and ask for the waiver as it's a innocent mistake from your side.